# How to remove a certain part of a string in scrapy for python

Tags: python, string, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to get a clean output because When I scrape the website it gives, reviewed 7/20/2015 so I am trying to strip it so it only shows 7/20/2015. This is what I've been trying and when I test it by itself making a mock dict and populate it with values this code works but not in scrapy. I assume `Field()` is just            `dict = {value:[],value2:[]}` so I dont know Why it does not work on `Field()`

Here's the code snippet

```
for j in range(len(item['date'])):
    item['date'][j][9:].strip()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the built-in [`re()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#using-selectors-with-regular-expressions) method of a Selector:

```
response.xpath("//div[@id='test']/text()").re(r"\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}")
```

Comment: Yeah this works I had to tailor your code to my xpath input. Thanks